Import ICS file using intent
i am using Pixel 6 Device having Androd 15
i am facing issue that when importing ics file using any other device the screen is perfect but when using Pixel 6  Device i am facing the issue same as in screenshot that screen is missing under status bar you can see
you can seee the image below

and when using any other device the output has not same problem
you can see everything is fine

I want to add events from calendar file but it hides add button under status bar that dont allow me to add
